# iOS 8: UITableView crashes on heightForRowAtIndexPath (worked fine on iOS7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsautoreleasepool

With the new released iOS8 i have experienced crashes in my TableViews that weren't there before.

I use the following code to calculate the cell heights. This worked wonderfully on iOS7, but crashes on iOS8.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 0);

  [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

  CGFloat height = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
  return height + 1;
}
```

> *** -[UITableViewCell release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7d2e2bb0

When this crash happens, i get the following Stacktrace: (Sorry for the Image, can't copy the text out of AppCode)
[image: Stacktrace]

Here's the Instruments output... 
[image: ReleaseRetainCount]

Has anybody seen this behaviour before, or has an idea on how this crash can be prevented?

Comment: Just po 0x7d2e2bb0 and u will get to know which object is being access after it is released. Also enable zombie then u might be able to debug with ease. In short, an object is released and you're trying to access it.

Comment: Hey walle84: I already have enabled zombie, thank you. My guess is that the AutoreleasePool releases the Cell, wich is later used by [tableView dequeReusableCell...]. But how can i prevent the AutoreleasePool to release the cell?

Comment: I addded your code of heightForRowAtIndexPath method into my sampleDemo and no crash occur in this method. U should check again by debugging and getting point of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it working now.

The thing is: In your custom UITableViewCell classes, do not set
`self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` (Even if you are using AutoLayout)

I don't know why, but when this is set, the crash happens.